# Get ViewModel of containerless element

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

In Aurelia when I want to access the view model of a DOM element which is an aurelia custom element I can use the `au` property which Aurelia attaches, like `componentElement.au.controller.viewModel`.

When my custom element is containerless (attribute `@containerless` on class level) the property `au` is not available.

This gist demonstrates this:
https://gist.run/?id=928f97f49c01c1db10d8bf4399f5c335

How can I access the viewmodel of a containerless custom component when I only have a reference to its DOM element?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can use `view-model.ref`. For instance:

```
<less-comp text="item three, containerless" view-model.ref="test"></less-comp>
```

Usage:

```
export class App {
  attached() {
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

Comment: This way the `less-comp` VM is available in the app, but it should be in the `list-comp` (where I currently output those console logs). Also how would this work if I I compose `less-comp` with `repeat.for`?

Answer (score 0):

Achieve what you want by hooking into `created` life cycle in your view model:

```
class ViewModel {
  created(owningView, view) {
    view.controller
    view.controller.viewModel // <-- this is what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: If doing this in `less-comp`, then `view.controller` is `undefined`. I guess because it is a containerless component. Also `view.controller.viewModel` would equal `this` so what's the point?

Comment: Didn't read question carefully, checked your usage, can see that what you want won't be supported by `@children`. Maybe there's away